# React Question about promise in a for loop

Tags: reactjs

I am in the process of learning React and making HTTP requests.

Recently Im trying to implement a dropdown for the webpage that Im working on. In my code I had to loop through an array of id, and make a post request for each of the id to extract the metadata. So Im encountering a problem with the dropdown options. The dropdown options are suppose to be the names for the corresponding id.

The array of id is an array of objects that looks like this

```
[{key: "someidnumber1", count: 5}, {key: "someidnumber2", count: 5}, {key: "someidnumber3", count: 10},....]
```

So what I did first is to loop through the id array, and make a post request on each of the id as parameter. This is inside my render method.

```
render() {
  return(
    <SomeOtherComponent>
      { //Do something to fetch the ids
        let promises = [];
        let names = [];
        let options = [];

        ids.map(id => {
          promises.push(
            axios
              .post(TARGET_META_URL, {
                filters: [
                  {
                    field: "id",
                    values: [id.key]
                  }
                ]
              })
              .then(response => {
                 // adding the name from the data into the names array
                 names.push(response.data[0].name);
              })
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
          // Wait for the promises to collection all the names
          // and pass into a new array
          options = [...names];
        }

        return (
          <Dropdown 
            options={options}
          />
        );
       }
    </SomeOtherComponent>
  );
}
```

My dropdown options after opening it is empty. So I did a couple console log and figured out that the options is declared outside the Promise.all so when the render() method is called, the dropdown takes in an empty array. I need help on how to setup the options for the dropdown so it waits for all the code before it finish running. I tried putting the second return inside the Promise.all() but I get an error method saying that render() doesn't have a return.

Comment: Ooookay, you don't embed state and logic inside the JSX like that. You need to do the API requests in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function and store the options in state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make another component which fetches the data and renders them once the responses have come back. Use `Promise.all` to wait for all of the Promises to resolve together.

```
const getName = id => axios
    .post(TARGET_META_URL, {
        filters: [
            {
                field: "id",
                values: [id.key]
            }
        ]
    })
    .then(response => response.data[0].name);
const AsyncDropdown = ({ ids }) => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        Promise.all(ids.map(getName))
            .then(setOptions)
            .catch((err) => {
                // handle errors
            });
    }, [ids]);
    return options ? <Dropdown options={options} /> : null;
}
```

And replace your original render method with:

```
render() {
  return(
    <SomeOtherComponent>
      <AsyncDropdown ids={ids} />
    </SomeOtherComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: So basically the request is made in another component, and includes as a child component, and pass back the returned data into this parent component?

Comment: You *could* shove it all into a single component if you wanted, but it'd look messy and would be more difficult to manage than it should be. Better to separate concerns when possible.

Comment: Ok, Im going to try to modify my code a little bit and see if it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help -

```
componentDidMount() {
    let promises = [];
    let options = [];
    ids.map(id => {
        promises.push(
            axios
            .post(TARGET_META_URL, {
            filters: [
                {
                    field: "id",
                    values: [id.key]
                }
            ]
        })
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
    // Wait for the promises to collection all the names
    // and pass into a new array
    options = response.map(res => res.data[0].name);
    this.setState({ options })
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <SomeOtherComponent>
        { this.state.options?.length ? <Dropdown options={this.state.options} /> : null }
        </SomeOtherComponent>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this way, but then it kept on giving me an empty dropdown. However, as @CertainPerformance suggested, making another component did help.

Comment: @user14459580 It should have worked ... I missed this.state.options to Dropdown prop in my answer ... corrected that.

Comment: oh, I see, u are setting up the option as state, yea it worked this way too